# Variable in foreach loop causing partial view to not render

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a partial view on a page that displays off an AJAX link. I'm trying to have the button names unique within the grid, but when I implement the code to do so it causes the partial view not to render...

In the partial view (Renders):

```
@foreach (var ht in Model)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="four columns alpha">
            @ht.Value
        </div>
        <div class="three columns omega">        
            <input type="button" value="delete" id="btnDelete" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

In the partial view (Does not render)

```
@foreach (var ht in Model)
{
    @{ var buttonName = "btnDeleteCampaign" & @ht.Id; }
    <div class="row">
        <div class="four columns alpha">
            @ht.Value
        </div>
        <div class="three columns omega">        
            <input type="button" value="delete" id="@buttonName" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

What part of that second block is keeping the partial view from rendering, and how do I accomplish my goal?

Comment: I can't tell why you're using it, but I think it might be either the `&` or `@` in the variable initialization.

Comment: somebody's been playing in VB I bet. wash that filth off before you come in this house! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `@{` and to concatenate the string, use a `+`

```
@foreach (var ht in Model)
{
    var buttonName = "btnDeleteCampaign" + @ht.Id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried it using + as well, but it didn't seem to work. Was probably due to the @{ around it. Thanks - working now with this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for initializing `buttonName`:

```
@{var buttonName = "btnDeleteCampaign" + ht.id}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `&` to concatenate strings in C#. Initialise your `buttonName` variable like this:

```
var buttonName = "btnDeleteCampaign" + ht.Id
```